# Are different datatype possible in a case expression?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I have this query

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77 IS NOT NULL OR dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77 <>'' 
       THEN MONTH(dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77)
     WHEN dbo.CFE_PPHY.P70 IS NOT NULL OR dbo.CFE_PPHY.P70 <>'' 
       THEN MONTH(dbo.CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.C10_2)
     ELSE COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR,dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77)+
          CONVERT(VARCHAR,dbo.CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.C10_2),'toto') END 
 AS CFELiasse_DateEffetEIRL_MM_N
FROM CFE_PPHY LEFT JOIN CFE_SERVICE_EVTS ON CFE_PPHY.colA = CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.colB
```

The `ELSE` part is giving me headaches.

The columns `CFE_PPHY.P77` and `CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.C10_2` have date time format. I'm turning them into `varchar`. Yet when I'm running the query, I have the following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'toto' to data type int.

Obviously, I cannot turn `toto` to an integer. Fair enough. However, from my point of view, I've converted the `datetime` format to a `varchar` format, so it should do the work.

Where am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: A case expression returns values for a column. The first two parts of your case expression are returning integers. MONTH(). You can't mix datatypes like that in a single column. You will have to convert those to varchar also. You also really need to specify a length on varchars instead of just using the default. The default is either 30 or 1 depending on usage. Are you 100% certain you know which is which? And if MS changes that at some point your code is broken.

Comment: The issue is that `CASE` doesn't support multiple data types, in your first two conditions you are returning an `INT` in the form `MONTH(blah)`. Either convert this to a `VARCHAR` or don't use "toto".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert all of your case expressions to varchar.  SQL is deciding to case the field as int so 'toto' is invalid.  If all expressions are converted to varchar this error should be solved.

http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2010/10/08/sql-server-simple-explanation-of-data-type-precedence/

Answer (score 3):

Have a closer look at your `case` expression: in the first and second conditional branches you're returning `MONTH(...` which is obviously integer.

But in third branch you're returning `varchar` thus SQL server tries to convert it to `int` according to data type of previous branches and failing to do it.

Answer (score 2):

Try like this,

```
SELECT CASE 
        WHEN dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77 IS NOT NULL
            OR dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77 <> ''
            THEN convert(VARCHAR, MONTH(dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77))
        WHEN dbo.CFE_PPHY.P70 IS NOT NULL
            OR dbo.CFE_PPHY.P70 <> ''
            THEN convert(VARCHAR, MONTH(dbo.CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.C10_2))
        ELSE COALESCE(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.C10_2), 'toto')
        END AS CFELiasse_DateEffetEIRL_MM_N
FROM CFE_PPHY
LEFT JOIN CFE_SERVICE_EVTS ON CFE_PPHY.colA = CFE_SERVICE_EVTS.colB
```

Answer (score 1):

First, when converting to a string, always include a length (in SQL Server).  The default length varies by context and may not be correct.

Second, the comparison of date/time values to `''` is not necessary.  This is not really valid value for a date/time -- although it does get converted to a 0 which is 1900-01-01.  The `NULL` comparison should be sufficient.  Otherwise, be explicit.

Third, string concatenation will return `NULL` if any of the arguments are `NULL`.

Fourth, table aliases make a query easier to write and to read.

As far as I can tell, your `case` is a bit over complicated.  In the `ELSE`, we know that `dbo.CFE_PPHY.P77` is `NULL`, because of the first condition.  So, how about:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN p.P77 IS NOT NULL
             THEN CAST(MONTH(p.P77) as VARCHAR(255))
             WHEN p.P70 IS NOT NULL
             THEN CAST(MONTH(e.C10_2) as VARCHAR(255))
             ELSE 'toto'
        END) AS CFELiasse_DateEffetEIRL_MM_N
FROM CFE_PPHY p LEFT JOIN
     CFE_SERVICE_EVTS e
     ON p.colA = e.colB;
```

Comment: Hi @gordon-linoff, thanks for your answer and the learning attached. I've carried on with your book. It is very interesting, I've just arrived at the chapter 3. Thinking about that, I need to carry on with the reading, will do that tonight.