# If-Then Statement In A SQL Query Insists On Trying To Convert To Wrong Type, Then Fails

Tags: sql, sql-server, if-statement

I have a SQL query, linking table 1 to table 2 via an inner join, containing this part in the select part of the statement:

```
select
table1.field1,
table2.field1,
CASE (table2.field1)
     WHEN -2 THEN ''
     ELSE table2.field2
END as table2Field2,
table3.field4
from...
```

I want to be able to return table2Field2 when it has a relevant value, ie: when the object represented in table2 is not null, so that table2.field1 does not have a value of -2. In this case, the value of table2Field2 should be blank instead of a meaningless value.

However, this returns 0 instead of the blank text. If I change this line:

```
 WHEN -2 THEN ''
```

to this:

```
 WHEN -2 THEN 'someText'
```

then it complains at me that it's trying to convert an int to a string, which I'm not. table2field1 is an int, but table2Field2 is a string, which is what we're actually returning here.

How do I state (even more specifically) in this query that I'm returning the string field as a string, and not something else as a string that isn't (a) a string, and (b) the thing I specified I'm returning please?

All suggestions welcome, many thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: What database do you use ? Thanks!

Comment: Can you return null?

Comment: CASE statement expects to return both the values from when clause and else clause to be of same datatype. You are trying to return 1 number and other string. Hence the error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [t-sql Different datatype possible in a case?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37615593/t-sql-different-datatype-possible-in-a-case)

Comment: You can probably resolve this by changing it to WHEN '-2' THEN ''

Comment: I tried the '-2' already, but still the same issue.

Comment: Thanks Ankit, you've got it. I had to cast the answer in the ELSE as a string for it to work. Thank you very much indeed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a `CASE` expression, all of the possible return values must be of the same data type. As written, the expression is trying to return one string and one integer.

If you want an empty string for your first output, you can `CAST` or `CONVERT` your second output to a character type value:

```
select
table1.field1,
table2.field1,
CASE (table2.field1)
     WHEN -2 THEN ''
     ELSE CAST(table2.field2 AS varchar(12)) --< 12 will cover any value of integer.
END as table2Field2,
table3.field4
from...
```

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible you have your `as table2field2` in the wrong location?

maybe try:

```
select
table1.field1,
table2.field1,
CASE (table2.field1)
     WHEN -2 THEN ''
     ELSE table2.field2
END as table2Field2,
table3.field4
from...
```

Comment: Good spot, but yes, I had it in the right place originally. I've written this out rather than copying and pasting as I wanted to simplify it a little for the purposes of posting in this question. I shall edit and amend that part now :)

Answer (score 1):

Because you do not want to answer me what is the database you use then I have to do it like this hehehe:

**SQL Server:** [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bc8d4d415b368f0f94e1db3b78660fd0)

```
select
t.col1,
CASE
     WHEN convert(char,t.col1) = '-2' THEN 'aaa'
     ELSE convert(char,(t.col2))
END test
from Tab1 t;
```

**Oracle** [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=fc3d0d0ca3a3968f2d8bd455f4382f4e)

```
select
t.col1,
CASE
     WHEN to_char(t.col1) = '-2' THEN 'aaa'
     ELSE to_char(t.col2)
END test
from tab1 t;
```

Comment: I was using SQL Server, but yes, well played.